# mail body size limit in utl_smtp

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have a procedure to send mail using utl_smtp.
What is the maximum mail body size that I can send and if my mail body size exceeds this limit, then how can I send it?

Answer (score 1):

Just send it in chunks:

```
    l_offset  := 1;
    l_amount := 1900;
    utl_smtp.open_data(l_connection);
    while l_offset < dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) loop
        utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection,
                            dbms_lob.substr(l_body_html,l_amount,l_offset));
        l_offset  := l_offset + l_amount ;
        l_amount := least(1900,dbms_lob.getlength(l_body_html) - l_amount);
    end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm):

> **Rules and Limits**   No limitation or range-checking is imposed by the API. However, you should be aware of the following size
>   limitations on various elements of SMTP. Sending data that exceed
>   these limits may result in errors returned by the server.
>
> Table 178-5 SMTP Size Limitation
>
> Element |  Size Limitation
>
> user | The maximum total length of a user name is 64 characters.
>
> domain |  The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 64
>   characters.
>
> path | The maximum total length of a reverse-path or forward-path is
>   256 characters (including the punctuation and element separators).
>
> command line | The maximum total length of a command line including
>   the command word and the  is 512 characters.
>
> reply line | The maximum total length of a reply line including the
>   reply code and the  is 512 characters.
>
> text line | The maximum total length of a text line including the
>    is 1000 characters (but not counting the leading dot duplicated
>   for transparency).
>
> recipients buffer | The maximum total number of recipients that must
>   be buffered is 100 recipients.

Anyway, I think if your email body is too big, the destination will reject it...

**UPDATE**
*Anyway, if you send so big data over email, something is wrong. You shoud use another solution. A client that reads data from database and presents it to the user in a friendly format.
There is oracle discoverer, or you can develop an application with java, or php... there are many options...*

Comment: What if The maximum total length of a text line including the is more than 1000 characters? can't i send the mail using UTL_SMTP. Is there any way to send the mail even if the lenghth of body is too huge> Request you to let me know if any

Comment: 1000 chars seems to be a smtp restriction. Probably won't work. Try UTL_MAIL. I'll update my response with some considerations.